# Using a scope to check if a related model has no other related models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to get a scope working.  I've outlined the simple models below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :attendances
end

class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Attendances  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I'm trying to do is write a scope on Attendances that checks for users that have no authentications.  Something along the lines of:

```
scope :fulfilled_without_user_authentications, lambda { includes(:authentications).where('authentications.id' => nil) }
```

However, obviously the direct relationship between attendances and authentications doesn't exist.

Should I be creating this link (using has many through), or is there a way of specifying this within the scope itself.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

try following and let me know if it works..

```
class Attendances  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :fulfilled_without_user_authentications, lambda { joins(:user => :authentications).where('authentications.user_id != users.id') }
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no joy.  I get back "Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you first need to rethink your relations.
Can a User have an attendance without being authenticated?

If not, I would refactor your relations to "has many through":

Comment: A User can have an attendance without an authentication.  Am I missing a way to refactor here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the approach I settled on, that works, was:

```
class User
  scope :with_authentications, where("id IN (SELECT user_id FROM authentications)")
  scope :without_authentications, where("id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM authentications)")
end

class Attendance
  scope :with_user_authentications, lambda {
    joins "INNER JOIN users ON users.id = attendances.attendee_id" and User.with_authentications
  }
  scope :without_user_authentications, lambda { 
    joins "INNER JOIN users ON users.id = attendances.attendee_id" and User.without_authentications
  }
end
```